# What are the mean and variance of the ratio of two lognormal variables?

Tags: normal-distribution

Ratios of two normally distributed variables (e.g X/Y) have no moments (e.g. means and variances) because Y can have zero values. However, lognormal variables have no zero values. How can I calculate the mean and variance of the ratio of two lognormal variables?

Comment: That's not the reason that the ratio of independent normals has no (central) moments. Indeed $\mathbb P(Y = 0) = 0$ in both cases.

Comment: What are the reasons that the ratio of independent normals has no (central) moments?

Comment: There's too much probability near the origin of the denominator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Note that $\log(X/Y) = \log(X) - \log(Y)$.  Since $X$ and $Y$ are lognormally distributed, $\log(X)$ and $\log(Y)$ are Normally distributed.

I'll assume that $\log(X)$ and $\log(Y)$ have means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$, variances $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y$, and covariance  $\sigma_{XY}$ (equal to zero if $X$ and $Y$ are independent) and are jointly normally distributed.  The difference $Z$ is then normally distributed with mean   $\mu_Z = \mu_X - \mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma^2_Z =  \sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Y - 2\sigma_{XY}$.

To get back to $X/Y$, note that $X/Y = \exp Z$, showing that $X/Y$ is itself lognormally distributed with parameters $\mu_Z$ and $\sigma^2_Z$.  The relationship between the mean and variance of a lognormal variate and the mean and variance of the corresponding normal variate is:

$\mathbb E(X/Y) = \mathbb E e^Z = \exp \{\mu_Z + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2_Z \}$

$\mathrm{Var}(X/Y) = \mathrm{Var}(e^Z) = \exp \{2\mu_Z + 2\sigma^2_Z\} - \exp \{2\mu_Z + \sigma^2_Z\} \>.$

This can be rather easily derived by considering the moment-generating function of the normal distribution with mean $\mu_Z$ and variance $\sigma^2_Z$.

Comment: A somewhat important point here is that $(\log X, \log Y)$ be jointly normally distributed. As you essentially note, there is a contrast here with the case of constructing a Cauchy by ratios of normals in that the result in your answer holds in much greater generality than the latter. :)

Comment: 1. Should your formula be used (instead of the naïve estimator such as the arithmetic mean and naïve variance of X/Y) if I want to use the ratio variable (X/Y) as an independent variable in linear regression analyses? If yes, how to do it by the statistical softwares? 2. Should X/Y ever be used as a dependent variable in linear regression analyses?

Comment: The coefficient of the covariance term should be $-2$ not $+2$.  Your formula gives the variance of the sum, not the difference.

Comment: I have made what I believe to be a couple of minor typo corrections. Please make sure I haven't, instead, introduced extra ones. :)

Comment: @probabilityislogic - Thanks, and cardinal too (+1 both), I was a little hurried when I did it.  Should have not hit the post button.  A lesson to be learned...

Comment: @Jinn-YuhGuh - there's no particular reason why $X/Y$ shouldn't be used as a dependent variable, if it makes sense to do so from a functional relationship between dependent and independent variables standpoint. As to your other question, I'm not sure what you mean - if you have observations $x_i$ and $y_i$, you'd probably construct your independent variable by $x_i/y_i$, not using averages.  However, if you want to estimate the mean and variance of $X/Y$, then you can do it as in the formulae, as, if you use the MLEs for the various parameters, you'll get the MLEs for the dist'n of $X/Y$.

Comment: @jbowman-The ratio (X/Y) is usually input into the software as a number (instead of its components X and Y). According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis , the slope of linear regression is calculated by the "naïve" means of dependent and independent variables and the "naïve" variances of independent variables (i.e. they are calculated according to the ordinary formula instead of yours). Thus, the estimates of the slope will be wrong.