# Distribution of transformed multivariate log-normal

Tags: lognormal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Let $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \Sigma)$ and $\mathbf{Y} = \text{exp}(\mathbf{X})$. If $Y_i$ is one of the components of $\mathbf{Y}$, what is the distribution of $\frac{\mathbf{Y}}{Y_i}$?

The answer to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21735/what-are-the-mean-and-variance-of-the-ratio-of-two-lognormal-variables/21740) question explains how to find the distribution of the ratio of log-normal random variables, however I am struggling to derive a result for the above multivariate case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved my own problem. Rewriting $\log \frac{\mathbf{Y}}{Y_{i^*}}$ as

\begin{align*}
\log \frac{\mathbf{Y}}{Y_{i^*}} &= \log \mathbf{Y} - \log Y_{i^*}\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{X} - X_{i^*}\mathbf{1} = (I - B)\mathbf{X}\\
\text{where } B_{i,j} &=\begin{cases} 0 & j \neq i^*\\ 1 & j = i^*\end{cases},
\end{align*}
we see that we simply need to find the distribution of an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) of a multivariate normal. Using the known result for this, we obtain

\begin{equation*}
\log \frac{\mathbf{Y}}{Y_{i^*}} \sim \mathcal{N}((I - B)\boldsymbol{\mu}, (I-B)\Sigma(I-B)^T)
\end{equation*}